Blazor Server App - Container CSS: Why the Large left margin?
I'm new to Blazor.  I have created the template application and the menu is bound to the left side of the screen.  I used this solution to place the menu horizontally at the top:
Now all of the pages of the application have a large left margin.  Checking the MainLayout.razor page, I see the class="container".  The container class in the bootstrap.min.css file has the left-margin set to auto.  For the life of me, I cannot determine why the system thinks there should be space in the margins.
The NavMenu.razor page:


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark mb-4">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">BlazingTopMenu</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler @NavButtonCssClass" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarCollapse"
                aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-label="Toggle navigation" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <span class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-md-0">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
                <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Home
            </NavLink>
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="counter">
                <span class="oi oi-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Counter
            </NavLink>
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="fetchdata">
                <span class="oi oi-list-rich" aria-hidden="true"></span> Fetch data
            </NavLink>
        </span>
     </div>
</nav>

@code {
    private bool collapseNavMenu = true;
    private string? NavBarCssClass => collapseNavMenu ? null : "show";
    private string? NavButtonCssClass => collapseNavMenu ? "collapsed" : null;

    private void ToggleNavMenu()
    {
        collapseNavMenu = !collapseNavMenu;
    }
}



The MainLayout.razor page:


@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<NavMenu />

<main class="container">
    @Body
</main>



If I remove the class assignment from , or just remove the  tag altogher, the formatting is more in line with what I want.  But I'm not sure that's a good idea.
Where is the left margin coming from?

NavLink related css is in site.css under your wwwroot folder. Check that css. Bootstrap css has nothing to do with this.
